# Disabling a Button / Prevent Editing

Tags: javascript, php, html, recaptcha

I ran into an Problem the Last Days and i hope someone could help me.

I'am currently coding an Login Page and to Prevent Bruteforce Attacks, i firstly protected it by checking if the User failed to login 5 Times and if Yes, then the User is blocked.

To Provide extra Bruteforce Security and Anti-Flood, i've used reCaptcha.

Now i've finished the Part where i can disable and Enable the Button if the reCaptcha is clicked or not.

The Only Problem i have right now is, everybody could just remove the "disabled" Tag in the HTML Editor (Inspect) and maybe there's a way to tell an Bruteforce Bot to do that, then Procceed with the Attack, and that's what i want to Prevent, so if somebody knows how i can prevent that the button is beeing able to be Disabled via Inspect (HTML Editor) please tell me.

I'am also Searching for an better way to Disable the Button if the Captcha wasn't clicked, so if there's somebody that could give me a Suggestion on that, i would be open for that.

Thanks already to Anyone who's trying to help and Have a Great Day!

Comment: "The Only Problem i have right now is, everybody could just remove the "disabled" Tag in the HTML Editor" Absolutely. This problem can't be solved client-side.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right to point out that you cannot just `disabled` the button on the HTML page, as that can be easily changed. Ultimately any way you try to disable the button on the webpage can be overcome.

**The solution is to send the CAPTCHA result to the *server*, and have the server make the decision regarding whether the request is allowed or not.** Then, report that back to the user. Trying to disable stuff or do this in Javascript on the browser won't work, I feel...

Comment: Thanks for the Tip, i've thought about this way too, the only Problem is i have no Idea how to get this done. 


I already know how to get an Response by the Post, but the Problem is how do i get an Answer from reCaptcha if the Captcha was been clicked before Posting anything.... 

That's the Part where my knowledge struggles right now...